# Fragment View on a threaded NavigationDrawerActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**My questions aren't in codes because I have the same problem all over my android application, and it's not in wrong syntax either it's in my lack of understanding of threads.**

I'm making a client-server socket application, a `NetBeans` application handling a `SQLite` database, and an android application that connect to this server and retrieve data from. Example: Android App sends a flag of the data it wants to retrieve, the server receives the flag, prepare the data and send it in sequence in which the android application receives by.

I tried many approaches to accomplish that, the Async task didn't work because I need different data on each action to update my views according to it, and Async task only gave me one background task that should be working for all the activities (Correct me if I'm wrong)

So I worked with the threads, I open a thread, establish a connection, send the flag and receive the data, update my views according to it.

This worked fine in my login activity for example, when a user press Login button, a thread is made to connect to the server, sends a flag that a user data is coming to the server, the server receives and check and so on.

My main question is, a navigation drawer is created now, on it's create it makes a thread that connects to the server to retrieve the data in its' items. I made fragment that use the same thing, when the user press a drawer item, a fragment should be created that connects to the server via thread that recieves some data that updates it's Views. and now we should append this fragment views to the navigation drawer activity, it doesn't work. because the activity itself is threaded.

Also, in other activities whenever I try to reach the threaded Navigation drawer activity through intent, it doesn't work even if I used this function for example

```
public void ThreadIntent(final Intent myIntent) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myIntent.putExtra("userid", TA_ID_User);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

how can I have this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can give multiple inner Asynctask classes for each activity and you can execute them in the onCreate() method. I think its better to go with Asynctask rather than moving with threads.

With Asynctask, inorder to update your views with server data use  onPostExecute() method.